# Can't connect to remote server on specific port

Tags: php, sockets, port, remote-server

I need to make a TCP/IP socket server in PHP.
So I downloaded an example from [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php) and tried it on my own machine (changed default script socket ip to 127.0.0.1). I opened it from web-browser (because I use XAMMP system, so I can't do a background working shell script), connected to 127.0.0.1:8175 by Telnet and it worked fine!
But now I have a problem:

I uploaded that script to remote server, opened port 8175 on the router and could not connect to the remote port from my computer. But I still can connect to the web and ssh ports on that server.
Any ideas?

If I asked that question in a wrong place, just say it. And... Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Is it just me, or is it that 20% of questions are now ended with "sorry for my bad english"?

Comment: @bjb568 ...
If i know that all i say will be clear for my interlocutor, i don't say it.

Comment: @bjb568 - No point slating people for being polite and explaining their post might not read as well as it could because English isn't their first language.

Comment: @webnoob Thanks! Any ideas about question?

Comment: @webnoob I never said there was anything wrong with it. It was just, uh... A comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set socket default IP to `127.0.0.1` you will be able to connect only from the machine running the script. So you need to change it something like your server's IP or `0.0.0.0` to accept all connections but take care of security measures.

Comment: No, you should try your server's IP or use `0.0.0.0` instead